# Redirecting /1234 to /profile.aspx?uid=1234

Tags: redirect, query-string

On IIS, I want to be able to redirect links like

(1) site.biz/people/1234 behind the scenes to

(2) site.biz/people/profile.aspx?id=1234.

In other words, whenever the server receives (1), it should secretly invoke (2) while leaving (1) in the browser address field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`IIS rewrite module`](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) which allows you to define rewrite rules. Here's an example of a rewrite rule you could have in your web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to profile.aspx">
            <match url="^people/([0-9]+)/" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="people/profile.aspx?id={R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: @Strychnine, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Minimal understanding? I demonstrate "minimal understanding"! What's wrong with either the question or the answer? This is a non-trivial subject; Visual Studio 2012 does not even recognize the "<rewrite>" tag, saying it's invalid, though it clearly works. Come on moderators, quit being pretentious.

Answer (score 0):

IIS has the http redirect module... You should enable that and configure the request and destination URL...  However there is an issue if you're redirecting more than 500 urls, you have to look at some custom code or a external 301 redirect package.

There's an article on technet on how to do it see link below.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930(v=ws.10).aspx